# Microservice Architecture - How to get user information from API gateway to microservice

Tags: laravel, rest, architecture, microservices, laravel-passport

I plan to set up a set of microservices with an API gateway, I am new to microservices architecture but the services I plan to add more services and keep this application highly extensible. The API gateway should manage the users and their permissions and should delegate the incoming requests to the underlying microservices. But my problem is, how can I create a relationship between the user at the gateway and an entity in a microservice.

[image: diagramm]

Like in the picture above i need to figure out  what is the best practice to deal with user relations in the underlying services. I want to implement all the services with laravel the gateway should use laravel\passport.

My thought was that the API gateway is responsible for authenticating the users and forwarding requests to the services behind the gateway. If the user is authenticated, he has access to the services through the gateway. But how can I provide the service with the information about the user, for example, if the user edits an item in service A, how can I store which user edited the item. What would be the approach to establish this relationship?

Comment: First, you need to issue a new token on auth server (API gateway): /register, /login, /user routes. /user API contains information about current user. Then, when a new request comes from the user with auth token (e.g. jwt token), you get user info from your auth server using /user route and this token. Hope I could explain.

Comment: @23nr1 It's not entirely clear for me what you're asking. Do you want to be able to identify the original user in the services behind the gateway? Are you wondering how to perform authentication/authorization? Or are you wondering how the gateway can manage user permissions and roles for any services you develop now and in the future in a sustainable way?

Comment: @pca My thought was that the API gateway is responsible for authenticating the users and forwarding requests to the services behind the gateway. If the user is authenticated, he has access to the services through the gateway. But how can I provide the service with the information about the user, for example, if the user edits an item in service A, how can I store which user edited the item. What would be the approach to establish this relationship?

Comment: @23nr1 Thank you for clarifying. I recommend that you extend your question with what you added with your comment. I ventured a response which will give you some pointers. This is a bit too complex and open-ended to be able to respond concretely, though :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many aspects to consider when selecting an approach, so basically answering your question will mostly be giving you pointers that you can research deeper on.

Here are some approaches you should review that will greatly depend on your service:

- Authentication/Authorization method for the platform as a whole
- How each individual service talks to each other (sync REST calls, messaging, GraphQL, GRPC, ...)
- How are individual service's secured (each service is public and does auth, every service is behind a secured network and only the gateway is public, service mesh takes care of auth, ...)

The most common auth method in REST based microservices is [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), with JWT tokens. I recommend that you look deeper into that.

*(Now just digressing a bit to demonstrate how much this varies depending on the use case and architecture)*

Taking OAuth and looking at your question, you still have different flows in OAuth that you will use according to the use case. For example, generating tokens for users will be different than for services.

Then you still need to decide which token to use in each service: will the services behind the gateway accept user tokens, or only service-to-service tokens? This has implications to the architecture that you need to evaluate.
When using user tokens you can encode the user ID in the token, and extract it from there. But if you use user tokens everywhere, then it assumes services only talk to each other as part of a user flow, and you are enforcing that through the use of a user token.
If you go with service-to-service tokens (a more common approach, I'd say) you need to pass the user ID some other way (again, this depends your chosen architecture). Thinking of REST, you can use the Headers, Request Params, Request Path, Request Body. You need to evaluate the trade-offs for each depending on the business domain of each service, which influences the API design.

If you don't use tokens at all because all your services are inside a secured network, then you still have to use some aspect of your protocol to pass the user ID (headers, parameters, etc...)